# Detect if a model has changed before calling save in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a database model that is being updated based on changes in remote data (via an HTML scraper).

I want to maintain a field called `changed` - a timestamp denoting when the last time that model's values changed from what they were previously (note that this is different from `auto_now` as these fields are updated every time a model's `save` method is called).

Here is my question:

In a model's `save` method, is there a straightforward way to detect if a model instance's current values are different from the values in the database? Or, are there any alternative methods to easily maintain a `changed` timestamp?

Comment: Has anyone had experience with `django-extensions`? They have a `TimeStampedModel` class that might do what I'm looking for but the documentation isn't very helpful (http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/model_extensions.html)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

http://code.activestate.com/pypm/django-dirtyfields/

Tracks dirty/changed fields on a django model instance.

Answer (score 35):

If you save your instance through a form, you can check `form.has_changed()`.

Comment: And if you want to know which field(s) changed: `form.changed_data`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like what you want is Signals: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/signals/

You could use a `post_save` signal to update a related field in another model to store the previous value. Then on the next go-round you'd have something to compare.

Comment: Up-to-date link: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/signals/

Answer (score 3):

You might try computing a checksum of the record values when you save them.  Then when you read it later, recompute the checksum and see if it has changed.  Perhaps the `crc32` function in the Python `zlib` standard module.  (I'm not sure what kind of performance this would have.  So you may want to investigate that.)

Comment: Interesting. Is there an easy way to look at the entirety of an object's data so that it can be easily checksummed? And is it possible that two identical (having the same field values) instances of an object have different "data" (the input read by our checksum function).

Comment: 1. The method I would use is to simply get all the field data, convert each to a string, concatenate it all, and checksum that.   2. It is theoretically possible to have two instances with different data come up with the same checksum, but it is very unlikely.  If you are really concerned about that, you can use a cryptographic hash function in which that be all but impossible; but it would be more expensive to calculate.

Comment: @dappawit you should also consider ordering of concatenation which could cause issues with your logic.  hash("a=1b=2c=3") != hash("a=1c=3b=2").  Regardless, another good approach.

Answer (score 0):

This library has tracks FK lookups.

https://github.com/mmilkin/django_dirty_bits