# django models detect if a user is trying to change a field

Tags: django

I'm saving a model and I need to detect if a user is trying to change a field and display an error:

```
 def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

     if self.status is being changed:
           error you cannot do that!
```

How can this be done is Django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if [django-dirtyfields](https://github.com/smn/django-dirtyfields/) package can help you, quote from docs:

```
(ve)$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from testing_app.models import TestModel
>>> tm = TestModel(boolean=True,characters="testing")
>>> tm.save()
>>> tm.is_dirty()
False
>>> tm.get_dirty_fields()
{}
>>> tm.boolean = False
>>> tm.is_dirty()
True
>>> tm.get_dirty_fields()
{'boolean': True}
>>> tm.characters = "have changed"
>>> tm.is_dirty()
True
>>> tm.get_dirty_fields()
{'boolean': True, 'characters': 'testing'}
>>> tm.save()
>>> tm.is_dirty()
False
>>> tm.get_dirty_fields()
{}
>>>
```

Also see:

- [Django: Check If a Field has Changed](http://zmsmith.com/2010/05/django-check-if-a-field-has-changed/)
- [Detect if a model has changed before calling save in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240670/detect-if-a-model-has-changed-before-calling-save-in-django)
- [In Django 1.4, do Form.has_changed() and Form.changed_data, which are undocumented, work as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710845/in-django-1-4-do-form-has-changed-and-form-changed-data-which-are-undocument)

Hope that helps.